# Similar tool as java2html but with support for Java 8

Tags: java

I am searching for an up-to-date java2html tool, which supports Java 8. In the past I used [java2html.com](http://www.vaegar.f9.co.uk/java2html/) which created [created really useful HTML code](http://www.vaegar.f9.co.uk/java2html/examples/Java2D_demo/index.html). However, I am in trouble now, because this tool not even supports Java 7 language constructs, not mentioning Java 8. If you know any similar **standalone** tool, which not only transfers the Java code to HTML, but also generates a browser and even it is a piece of cake to integrate it with Ant/Maven/Gradle, please let me know.

Comment: Why you dont use `javadoc`?

Comment: Because it does not display the (coloured) source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use javadoc's -linksource option, however, it does not colour the code. A workaround might be a javascript solution running on node.js and colouring the code with highlight.js. I chose this solution and automated the highlight.js integration with gradle.